# Where can I find what kind of questions are accepted on specific Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, questions, off-topic, scope

As an example, on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), questions about food-related health issues are not encouraged, but questions about utensils are accepted. I got to know this from comments on other posts.

I know about the general Stack Exchange FAQ. But how can I find the specific rules about what kinds of questions are OK of each site in Stack Exchange?

Comment: In their [help]? In the specific case you mention: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: While the above comment is correct, it would help the sites to have a description of where *you tried* to find the information you're looking for. I'm not saying "show your work". I'm saying that in order to make changes to make such information easier to find for people who were thinking along the same lines as you are, the developers need to know where you expected to find this information. Without hearing from you as to where you tried to find links to this information, we all have to *just guess* at what improvements could be made to make the information more findable.

Comment: Admittedly, just looking at the Ask Question page, there are some obvious places where the on-topic page in the Help Center should be explicitly linked, but it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often joke about SE having statutes, and case law.

The help pages should give you an overview of the site. They're mostly fixed - and not that different across sites

It feels like you're looking for 'case law' or local 'rules' and interpretations of rules as fit the site. For more specific discussions and site quirks, you would want to search the local meta -  you can access this via the site switcher. I'm fairly sure you can find what you're looking for for say a search for [health](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=health) for example

Comment: Not really (well, not at all) clear what are statutes (and case law) in this context?

Comment: The help center, coc and other formal rules are statutes- fixed rules, and meta is the interpretations of those and cover situations they don't, they're case law.

Comment: This would be a *much* better answer if it *actually said something about each site's on-topic page*, rather than just generically pointing people at the Help Center. In other words, this is currently answering the question "Where can I find rules about a site?" instead of what the question is asking "Where can I find *what kind of questions are accepted* on specific Stack Exchange sites?" IMO, the text of the question is quite clearly asking for information that's given on the on-topic and off-topic pages, rather than generic rules about the the site(s).

Comment: Op did mention reading it, hence the focus on meta

Comment: Found it. The "Help" link. I was expecting it to be at the right side of the page. But it's at the bottom. Surprised at the number of downvotes my question got. It's like as though asking a genuine question is frowned upon. Guys, when such information is usually provided on the top or sides of various websites, one does not expect to find it at the bottom. That too in the footer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike I don't see anything from the OP saying that they had seen the on-topic page. They said they have seen "the general StackExchange FAQ", but that's not necessarily the on-topic page. Is there a deleted comment that says they've seen the on-topic page?

Comment: @Nav The link to the help center is under the topbar icon that is a "?" in a circle that is at the top-right of the page one icon to the left of the rightmost icon.

Comment: @Makyen; Thanks. Found it. It initially didn't seem like something that'd give specific info about a particular StackExchange site.

Comment: "It initially didn't seem like something that'd give specific info about a particular StackExchange site" - but if it instead just said the word "Help", it would, somehow? I can't understand the reasoning.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft and their ilk have diluted the value of on-line help to the point where many users now simply expect nonsense documentation like "The Help menu provides help" instead of actually useful information.

Comment: Its still better than a ? . I'm not a fan of the pictographic top bar and less than first order retrievability of adjunct site resources like meta and chat. Its *not* great design, IMO and a little hostile unless you know its there.

Answer (score 4):

Every site on the Network has a unique On-Topic page in its Help Center outlining specifically what is and isn't within the scope of that particular site.

For Cooking.SE, that's https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, but every single one lives at the same relative URL, `$site://help/on-topic`.

You can get to it by clicking the help <kbd>`(?)`</kbd> button on the right side of the top nav bar of any site, and selecting "Help Center":

> [image: Top bar dropdown menu from help button, with "Help Center" as the second option below "Tour"]
> [image: Help Center landing page, with the "What questions can I ask about here?" link under the "Asking" heading highlighted]

Each site also has its own [tour page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) (`$site://tour`, also reachable via the top bar help button shown above), which covers the same information (and more, though sometimes in slightly less detail):

> [image: Screenshot of the ask about/ don't ask about sections on Cooking.SE's tour page]

There are a *lot* of sites on the Network, so I can't tell you with certainty that every site's on-topic and tour pages are sufficiently detailed– but that's an excellent place to start. From there, site Metas are a great next step for [investigating or asking about a site's](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

Answer (score 2):

While the public Q&A platform is the same for all Stack Exchange sites and SO has few features unavailable to other sites, all sites have a tour, help center and a child Meta.

Before the site launch, the CM and design teams have "filled in the blanks" of the tour and help center "templates". Every community has the option to customize them. Some might be edited by diamond users, others might require special skills and permissions; some might only require community consensus, and others might require a revision to be included in Stack Overflow, Inc. backlog and might take some time.

Ideally, you should start by reading the tour. It is intended to provide a broad overview, including what type of questions can be asked. If you need more details from what you have found on the tour, look at the corresponding community's help center homepage and the following help articles:

- How do I ask a good question?
- What topics can I ask about here?
- What type of question should I avoid asking?

I haven't reviewed all the tour, help center and meta of the 181 communities, but I have reviewed some. I have learned that many have not customized their resources. Because of this, on some sites, the only way is to look at the site and learn what questions are accepted from the available questions. In some communities, you might have to be bold and patient: post a question and wait for the community's feedback.

Comment: Every site has a "What topics can I ask about here?" entry in the [help] that is specific to that site.

Comment: Yes, but not every community pays attention to it.